# Xero - Attach a file to an existing invoice using Attachment API

Tags: laravel, xero-api

Documentation => [Attachment API](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/attachments#POST).

Although access_token is correct, whenever I upload a file, I always got 401 error(unauthorized).

pls, explain with an example of your request, including request headers?
My request header is:

xero-tenant-id: `tenant_id`

Authorization: `Bearer access_token`

Content-Type: `image/png`

Content-Length: `1000`

Thanks.

Comment: Does your scope include the correct permissions? I think it's accounting.attachments needed for this. https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/scopes

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add accounting.attachments. Thank you droopsnoot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Attachments require different scopes to use.

Have you included the 'accounting.attachments' scope in the scopes requested when authorising the connection?

Copied from: [XERO PHP SDK - Createinvoiceattachment throws 401 Unauthorized error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675274/xero-php-sdk-createinvoiceattachment-throws-401-unauthorized-error)

it worked to me

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31974502)